# I keep getting this error: TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: django, reactjs

I am trying to create a site using django and react, but when I try to view it, I keep getting this error    `TypeError: data.map is not a function`. below is my code, I don't seem to know the problem

I am trying to create a site using django and react, but when i try to view it, i keep getting this error    TypeError: data.map is not a function. below is my code, i don't seem to know the problem

````
class ProductList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        loading: false,
        error: null,
        data: []
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        axios
          .get(productListURL)
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data, loading: false });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.setState({ error: err, loading: false });
          });
      }

      render() {
        const { data, error, loading } = this.state;
        return (
          <Container>
            {error && (
              <Message
                error
                header="There was some errors with your submission"
                content={JSON.stringify(error)}
              />
            )}
            {loading && (
              <Segment>
                <Dimmer active inverted>
                  <Loader inverted>Loading</Loader>
                </Dimmer>

                <Image src="/images/wireframe/short-paragraph.png" />
              </Segment>
            )}
                <Item.Group divided>

                     {data.map(item => {
                        return <Item key={item.id}>
                                    <Item.Image src={item.image} />

                                    <Item.Content>
                                        <Item.Header as='a'>{item.title}</Item.Header>
                                        <Item.Meta>
                                        <span className='cinema'>{item.category}</span>
                                        </Item.Meta>
                                        <Item.Description>{item.description}</Item.Description>

                                    </Item.Content>
                                </Item>
                    })}
                </Item.Group>
            </Container>
            );
        }
    }

export default ProductList```
````

Comment: Does the ajax request result in an error ?

Comment: @Kelechi Ezumah Can you share the res.data from your Axios call? seems like it's not an array to iterate through

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint after your destructure to check that data is an array vs an object, after the rerender once the request is fulfilled. I am guessing your request is return is an object.